# Null pointer execption even when object is not null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am facing a somewhat weird problem. I am trying to get the string from resources, I have a non `activity class` where I get the `context` like this:

```
App app= App.getInstance();
if (app != null) {
    return app.getResources().getString(R.string.overview);
}
```

while debugging the control goes inside the if statement which means `app` is not null.

The App class:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App app = new App ();

    private App () {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        if (app == null) {
            app = new App ();
        }
        return app;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be fine, but when I run it I get null pointer exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
        at com.emanager.ui.adapters.HomePagerAdapter.getPageTitle(HomePagerAdapter.java:45)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:773)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:764)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:716)
        at com.emanager.ui.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have tried some other ways, but does not seem to fix it.

How do I fix this exception?

Comment: Got a solution? post it when you get please @NongthonbamTonthoi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is you declared a default constructor of Application class as a private constructor.Although it is not necessary to declare a constructor at all but if you declare it then you must make it public [@MikeM.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) suggested this in comments of another answer of this question here

Just do this

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App app;
   public App()
      {
        //got a public constructor
      }
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       app = this;
   }

   public static App getInstance() {
       return app;
   }
}
```

and in your AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Ok make sure you got it inside AndroidMenifest.xml @NongthonbamTonthoi

Comment: Mike M's comment fixed my issue anyway but you answered it

Comment: Ok yup saw it now !! Chill @NongthonbamTonthoi

Answer (score 4):

You should not create Application by your self, it will be created once your app run before activity start.

try this:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App app;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       app = this;
   }

   public static App getInstance() {
       return app;
   }
}
```

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Also make sure you've specified your `Application` class as the `name` of the `<application>` in the manifest.

Comment: @MikeM. your comment fixed it, never thought it would be the cause. Thanks

Comment: edited your answer when you try to name your application class inside your menifest file it shows you an error say Application class do not have default constructor so you must have to make a public constructor inside Application class to make it work @Harlon

Comment: public constructor is not requisite when extend Application, I used it in my project before.

Comment: Do we need to make a constructor public must? @MikeM. because i got an error when trying this code in  menifest file it shows you an error say Application class do not have default constructor but the guy got a solution who asked this question just by follow your comment but how it can be because he declare a private constructor

Comment: sorry guys it still shows the same error. Is it a bug in AS?

Comment: Made constructor public added in name in manifest, but I still get the same error

Comment: have you tried my code because it worked perfect in my case @NongthonbamTonthoi

Comment: just give a full code in your question again @NongthonbamTonthoi

Comment: The same error? maybe you can set breakpoint in that line and debug it, clean project before doing this

Comment: @Tapanparmar You don't need to explicitly implement a constructor at all, but if you do, and you make it `private`, that will fail. The solution is to remove the constructor, specify the correct `name` in the manifest, and implement this answer. I would point out that this answer has no `private` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern is a good one, although I do not understand why would you need all of that. Would you explain why exactly do you need to have your app instance available through the whole app?

Regarding your question, `getApplicationContext()` method should be a way for you.

Comment: I needed to have singleton so that I can access context in classes which donot extend activity